# Stack pointer values in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly, x86

I wonder why the values of the stack pointer in IDA Pro have similar values.
[image]

Can anyone explain their meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call pushes the address of the next mnemonic on the stack. But the ret in the function explode_bomb will also pop this address from the stack. So the stack value at 0x8048b6e will stay the same. If the jump at 0x8048b67 is taken the stack will also be unchanged.